# Why does the first (and only the first!) access to a Spring Data repository finder always rollback my EJB transaction?

Tags: jakarta-ee, spring-data, ejb-3.0

I have a strange phenomenon in my application.

I'm inside a local stateless EJB and want to call another local stateless EJB, which results in the following exception:

```
javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Client's transaction aborted
```

While i was researching the problem i found out that usually the reason for this is a runtime exception somewhere in the code inside the first EJB before trying to call the second (inner) EJB.

Apparently even when that runtime exception is catched and handled, it's mere existence is enough to mark the transaction as rolled back. so far so understandable.

the thing is i'm not aware of any runtime exceptions in the relevant code. But i was able to locate the single line of code that causes this and it is the access to a Spring Data repository finder, like this one:

```
@Inject
CompanyRepository companyRepo;

Company company = companyRepo.findByName(inputVO.getCompanyName());
```

I have several repositories and it doesn't matter which one i call, they all cause this effect.

BUT, only during the first call after a redeploy of the application. After that everything works fine until i redeploy the application or restart the Payara server.

oh and by the way, the call to the finder-method always returns with a valid result and no "visible" exception even on the first call.

I assume there is some runtime exception inside the Spring Data code that is atched and handled and therefore not visible to me. Maybe some sort of "lazy initialization" where stuff only gets initialized after an exception indicates that it wasn't before? I don't know...it's just a hunch.

Anyway, i was curious to hear if someone knows how to work around this? (doing a dummy finder call inside a @PostConstruct seems kinda "not elegant")

Or maybe someone even knows the source of this and how to avoid it alltogether?

for reference i'll include my applicationContext.xml below (but keep in mind i'm not running in a Spring container, I'm in a Payara server. I only use the Spring Data libraries from the Spring Framework):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
        xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
        xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
        xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa"
        xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
        xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.1.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.1.xsd">

    <jpa:repositories base-package="de.otto.cccs.customerscoring.entities" />

    <tx:jta-transaction-manager />
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <context:component-scan base-package="de.otto.cccs" />

    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"
        p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory" />

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/COR99TSDatasource" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="default" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform"
                    value="org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent really found a solution for this, but since it was related to another issue ([CDI: Injecting single instance works, but injecting Instance<> does not. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712928/cdi-injecting-single-instance-works-but-injecting-instance-does-not-why/45726427#45726427)) and the solution  to that problem was not to use EJB's but plain Java classes instead, my problem with the rolled back EJB transaction went away, too ... since i'm not using EJB's anymore.

So it's not an ideal answer, I realize that, but thats what i'll work with for now.